# Is there a particular definition for the partial derivative of internal energy with respect to volume at constant temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics

If we have specific internal energy $u=u(T,v)$ then the total differential of $u$ is given by
$$du(T,v)=\left ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial T} \right )_vdT+\left ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} \right )_{T}dv$$
where

$$c_v\equiv \left (\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}  \right )_v$$

Is there any particular usage of $\left ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} \right )_{T}$? I know it can be expressed in the following form:

$$\left ( \frac{\partial u}{\partial v} \right )_T=T\left ( \frac{\partial p}{\partial T} \right )_v-p$$

I understand what it "means", but I don't know if it has a particular meaning that is significant.

Comment: Are you asking whether it has a "name?"

Comment: $(\partial U/\partial V)_T=0$ for an ideal gas and states  that its energy is a function of temperature only. The full eqn. is needed when working with  a real gas, such as described by van-der-Waals or similar eqn.

Comment: @Chet Miller Yes, essentially.